# Generate a random number 4 times no repeating Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am wanting to generate a random number between 1-100, but I am only wanting to generate those numbers once each time. I have a loop that runs 3 times to run the .Math and then push that into an array. But I dont want the situation where it generates the same number more than once.

I have put 21 in the allAnswers[] array as that is something that will stay consistent. Is there a way to generate and then check that array if that number exists and then run the .math again?

```
function buttonGenerator(){
    var allAnswers = [21],
        randomizer = [];

    // Generates 3 random answers
    for(a = 0 ; a < 3; a++) {
         wrongAnswers = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
         allAnswers.push(wrongAnswers);
    }

    // Generates random buttons while inputting the correct and incorrect answers randomly
    for(i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
        var buttonArea = $("#answerOptions");
        input = $('<button class="col-xs-6 btn btn-primary"></button>');
        input.appendTo(buttonArea);
    }

    shuffle(allAnswers);
    console.log(allAnswers);
}

buttonGenerator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to check if the array has the value before pushing:

```
if (allAnswers.indexOf(wrongAnswers) === -1) {
  allAnswers.push(wrongAnswers);
}
```

Comment: Would you not go if (!allAnswers.indexOf(wrongAnswers)) to check if it doesnt yet exist in the array?

Comment: Great. I see that when I randomize like that it pushes my array [21] out of position 0 

[41, 44, 28, 21]

Is there a way to keep it at position 0?

Comment: Ah wait. Ignore that. Forgot I was running a shuffle function